# Limit of memory size in an app

Tags: java, android, caching, memory, bitmap

I'm creating Android app which has storing photo funcionality. I noticed that it works slowly, hence I decided to create cache which I store the smallest photo (viewed in gridView) in. 
I created class:

```
 public class PhotoCache {
     public static Map<String, Bitmap> photos = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
     public static long size = 0;
 }
```

Then If I want to load bitmap in my app, firstly I check if it is not present in photos variable. If it is then I take it from there. Otherwise I load bitmap from memory and add to photos varialble. The problem which I anylizing now is the size of cache. Every time when I'm adding bitmap to photos variable I'm also adding its size to long variable:

```
 PhotoCache.size += newBitmap.getByteCount();
```

Then I print the value of size to observe its growing. It shocked me that after loaded a couple of bitmpas its size is about: 26527680 bytes and there's not any outOfMemory error raised. It is very strange for me why Android allows me to have that big number of bytes in memory. 
Now I want to secure my app and I have to know the limit of memory which I can store in photos. 
PS. I know that there is some solutions in Android to cache bitmaps, but I want to use my own.

Comment: Have you add largeheap= true

Comment: You can reduce the size of the image with the help of reducing resovlation and compress actual image it will be helpful for you

Comment: You can call maxMemory() on a Runtime object to see how many total bytes of heap your app is allowed to use.